# urlbased loadbalancing of websocketconnections in Kubernetes with Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, routes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress

I want to use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by` for websocket connections of multiple clients, where related clients (based on URL) should stick to the same server.

Ingress-nginx seem to rebalance traffic when something changes the number of replicas (pod goes down and will be auto replaced by a new one or the number is increased by runtime scale).

The problem with that rebalance is that it does not terminate existing connections. So websocket connections that already exist (for an already hashed URL) stay on pod A while new connections to the same URL suddenly are distributed to a new spawned pod B.

This is my ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: websocket-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$1"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /socket-service/?clients/(.*)/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: websocket-test
          servicePort: 80
```

Is there a configuration to control this behaviour in some way, either by turning off "rebalancing" or by automatically terminating existing connections?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't found anything to prevent Ingress-nginx from "rebalancing" when pods change.

In the end I have skipped using Ingress for this at all and I'm doing the routing in a haproxy pod that is in front of my socket-service which itself is now a stateful set so I can assign fixed DNS names for each socket-service instance. For the haproxy, I've created a lua script to do the routing with a deterministic rule so that the same url will always be routed to the same stateful-set instance.

Comment: @Jens Many thanks for raising that question. Is it resolved by now and if not could you somehow share your workaround, as this would be very helpful to me as well.

Comment: I haven't had a look into nginx since I'm not using it in my current project. I also don't have the code from my workaround but what i did in that mentioned lua script in the haproxy was to extract a UUID in my url (the id of the shared resource that several connections wants to access) and used a modulo to get a number from 0 to amount of instances - 1, from there I routed the request to the stateful-set instance in my cluster. So I got a deterministic behaviour which service a request will be routed to.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you can look into the [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/) and [Istio](https://istio.io/) direction.

You might be interested in [LoadBalancerSettings.ConsistentHashLB](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings-ConsistentHashLB) flag:

> Consistent Hash-based load balancing can be used to provide soft
>   session affinity based on HTTP headers, cookies or other properties.
>   This load balancing policy is applicable only for HTTP connections.
>   The affinity to a particular destination host will be lost when one or
>   more hosts are added/removed from the destination service.

From [Envoy Supported load balancers - ring-hash](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/load_balancing/load_balancers#ring-hash) documentation

> The ring/modulo hash load balancer implements consistent hashing to
>   upstream hosts. Each host is mapped onto a circle (the “ring”) by
>   hashing its address; each request is then routed to a host by hashing
>   some property of the request, and finding the nearest corresponding
>   host clockwise around the ring. This technique is also commonly known
>   as “Ketama” hashing, and like all hash-based load balancers, it is
>   only effective when protocol routing is used that specifies a value to
>   hash on.
>
> Each host is hashed and placed on the ring some number of times
>   proportional to its weight. For example, if host A has a weight of 1
>   and host B has a weight of 2, then there might be three entries on the
>   ring: one for host A and two for host B. This doesn’t actually provide
>   the desired 2:1 partitioning of the circle, however, since the
>   computed hashes could be coincidentally very close to one another; so
>   it is necessary to multiply the number of hashes per host—for example
>   inserting 100 entries on the ring for host A and 200 entries for host
>   B—to better approximate the desired distribution. Best practice is to
>   explicitly set minimum_ring_size and maximum_ring_size, and monitor
>   the min_hashes_per_host and max_hashes_per_host gauges to ensure good
>   distribution. With the ring partitioned appropriately, the addition or
>   removal of one host from a set of N hosts will affect only 1/N
>   requests.
>
> When priority based load balancing is in use, the priority level is
>   also chosen by hash, so the endpoint selected will still be consistent
>   when the set of backends is stable.

Comment: The cited documentation sounds like it would have the same behaviour than the nginx I'm asking for: As soon as the "set of backends" is unstable, it could redecide the "map" which hash belongs to which backend-server so future requests for this hash could be "sticky" on another host. In HTTP-calls this could be fine, but not with websockets since the existing connection will not be terminated and stays on the backend it belonged to when it initially connected.